# Quando o método setSelectionRange de HTMLInputElement pode ser utilizado?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estudando sobre a estrutura de um elemento [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) cheguei ao método [`setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange), que faz a seleção do texto entre as posições definidas pelas parâmetros, i.e. `input.setSelectionRange(0, 8)` irá selecionar os caracteres entre as posições 0 e 8 do valor do elemento `input`. Porém, vi um comportamento que, a princípio, me pareceu estranho e ainda não encontrei fontes oficiais que o explicasse.

Considere o exemplo abaixo: um campo texto e um botão; tanto quando o campo texto receber o foco quanto o botão ser pressionado, o conteúdo do campo deveria ser selecionado entre as posições 0 e 8, no caso "Anderson".

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

input.addEventListener("focus", function (event) {
  this.setSelectionRange(0, 8);
});

button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  input.setSelectionRange(0, 8);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Anderson Carlos Woss">
<button>Selecionar</button>
```

Como é possível verificar, o conteúdo é selecionado corretamente quando o campo recebe o foco, mas ao pressionar o botão, nada acontece. Esse comportamento foi verificado tanto no Opera, Firefox quanto no Chrome e, curiosamente, funciona como esperado no IE11 e Edge. Nenhuma mensagem aparece no *console*.

Esse comportamento é o esperado nesta situação? Se sim, há alguma fonte oficial que explique o motivo de ser assim? Se não, por quê não funcionou em alguns navegadores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que isso acontece porque só é possível selecionar conteúdo em elementos que estejam em foco. Ainda que não encontrei isso escrito, faz sentido e [no exemplo da MDN é isso que fazem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange#Example). A referência mais próxima e indireta que encontrei foi [esta *nota*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select#Notas) relativa ao método `.select`:

> Executar `element.select()` não irá necessariamente focar o *input*, por isso é frequentemente usado em conjunto com `HTMLElement.focus()`.

Uma maneira de contornar isso é chamar o `input.focus();` dentro do handler de `click`.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

input.addEventListener("focus", function (event) {
  this.setSelectionRange(0, 8);
});

button.addEventListener("click", () => input.focus());
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Anderson Carlos Woss">
<button>Selecionar</button>
```

Comment: De fato, é isso. Estou utilizando isso em um elemento customizado com o Stencil e ao chamar o método `setSelectionRange` do elemento quero que seja executado o mesmo do `input` interno. Com o `focus` funcionou, mesmo que o `select` havia funcionado sem precisar definir o foco. Obrigado.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ótimo. Era bom isso ser mais claro nas specs do HTML5 ou da EcmaScript.